# Angularjs - showing spinner for $resource

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how to show a spinner while I retrieve data from my database.

I have a spinner already added and I have added a ng-show like so:

```
<img ng-show="loading" src="spinner.gif" />
```

My service looks like this:

```
myServices.factory('ChannelsService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/channels', {}, {
    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    create: { method: 'POST' }
  })
});
```

and my Controller:

```
ChannelsService.query(function(response) {
  $scope.channels = response;
});
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `loading` to `true` sometime before the `query` call, then set it to `false` once the `query` returns.

```
$scope.loading = true;
ChannelsService.query(function(response) {
    $scope.channels = response;
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for that - do you know how I can keep if on for a minimum of say 1 second?

Comment: check out angular's [`$timeout` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)